# Partially specifying the type of a function type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a use-case where I have a bunch of functions which have to meet certain criteria, i.e:

1. each function has to take exactly 2 parameters, which would be a `string` and an `Array<K>`
2. have to return a Promise of *unspecified type*, which has to be inferred by TS machinery, the type cannot be `unknown`, `any`, etc. because it will override the type inference

In essence, I'm looking for some magic type like:

```
type MagicType<K> = (str: string, keys: Array<K>) => Promise<infer>;
```

so that these functions would type-check: and return inferred type:

```
const f1: MagicType<number> = async (str, keys) => {
    return '42'
}
// expecting typeof f1 === (string, Array<number>) => Promise<string> 

const f2: MagicType<number> = async (str, keys) => {
    return keys.length;
}
// expecting typeof f2 === (string, Array<number>) => Promise<number> 

// note lack of `async` keyword
const f_error2: MagicType<number> = (str, keys) => {
    return keys.length;
}
// expecting to be a compilation error, since number is not Promise<unknown>
```

My trials and (only) failures can be found here: [TS-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGJK6drQIwGcAuoUCcCeE57wFApYAOApqALICGA5gJYDGAKqWQgDwDSANKAEqgAvKACuAOwDW4gPYB3cQD5hoABSoMALlAb642n0lksSbQEEMGalm6KAlMOUAFDDIC29JGQ79FAbgICEFBGdxJ6ABsyJD4AI1E0GQA3Mkt6ABNo9AALCj0AM1SMMnT0NjVdfQc5ehRssSlZBVBg2TRaGRl0glDxVFAyAA9qNxIogDEJRhR6GXEEZmwEbRoGFjZOcVE3WNTlEWokLHFGCsxDYyQHIWUAbwJQR9BilFEMcVAAAwASW6MTADaAAYALoAX0%20oAAPlCdJgAmCAkEwKFRpFonEEqBkkUMlk6nlxIVLCUyuQ1FsdhhqrV6hJpPIPq0ZO1Ot1ev0hiMxmRJicZnMAEyLLDLKh0Jiscibba7DD7UCHY6ndTnUD-K6OUD3J7PMivd7qy7AkHQ2EaAB0UX0dQRSORuHwTvggvEpUwOGdXvARHKq0lbEFthUHGYilVWjhGD0BiNJnMlmstmuymYSOCAAEUEgALRDcjTPOWGQYHpzTnDUYTKYC%20YiwUrCXrchBylyhVKk5nDAXEwp7UPJ4vN4fH5-Y2giFmqN2h0AERkWTaITC6IdWdz%20bIhaKJbLfTQXKrvJrs3EwuwDfFaylZFbsr2Kk7Ko0vc1NwHuuHho1JunlutWhbQIRFAmCYhyX4aJRAiFBbwQFQoINcRbw4CCyBkfIBkrHk%20WmM8FkvfwHXQgRoNg29BUQ-UR1Q9DMOw7lq35M8LywQViOCDk0AwMUoKQGC4I2FQAHIAGZBREgIuPLHir34wTKJUCT7WCb1nVAMSMHdbBHXUuAHQASREtxFViKJ0BkUASFccgMAiHBMnyPQKHyU85ms6grDcfVUhiMQkBjL43P5OZIX%20OQS1KeI0GM0oInoIxLJ0At6HyHA6moNACT1ZDQCSagIlEChKAAVQAZWYUBdkVUAXHcTwyB4B0kCsupPFADrZFADouk0X1yQAUUGAsUBKJwvJGJBgxEAFKljCwrBsLhFBBAhn1AEL8I8o9cPcutsDE1QLROkhJrcUxQGG0bxvO6a2z2BwdSHGjDREgAWSSQIdXZGGoUQvGxDwUBmfRFSOLsGBSJBQG63dSy22tGOPPDazYo6TotM7vMu67tzG9IJpxjgHvlJ7B0eb8Pg%20r6wTAsAAaC2gyHEVImE2-bQAAIkwJhJC50B0kXGHl0ijBJAGWlUj4VQYoGIkS0YLJqA5liPJQKyaufOwHSFpcWRXNELLkXIPhyxGz06mGADkAHkqo2nNQBNph6g6k2stAQzneocQUAIC2dpw5jtvEMSRTE0Nw0x7Gpu0PHplu4nSfsbR6o8Lwo8-F68ppkTvt14XYYN1FwmN02clczmOsd53sldq26897251t0A7aquRff9jbA4%20XaQ9rd6I6j47Tru%20ORvxpOppJh8ybT1wM%208MNs8p17qc%20-OwSAA)

Any help appreciated. I know this is most likely a corner-case, but I'd like to know if it's possible. Many thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need two generics, one for the input and one for the output

Answer (score 2):

I see two options og handling this case:

1. you are providing explicit return type:

```js
const f1: MagicType<number, string> = async (str, keys) => '42'
```

2. providing extra function in order to infer return type:

```js
type MagicType<K> = (str: string, keys: Array<K>) => Promise<any>;

const infer = <Cb extends MagicType<number>>(cb: Cb) => cb


const infered = infer(async (str, keys) => '42')

const result = infered('hello', [1, 2, 3]) // Promise<string>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQwOYEsDGAVSUA8BpAPhgF4YAKAZxACcAuGK6lAOyQBoYBrKMC%20gQWrUEYfAQCUJIgAVqAewC2KCrgTMwBANzBgaOcyowWAMyjUSMHAGEARjCgAPEFGYATCvGTos0HMwCuCjZmBARkaDb0tpLERBE6uvqGJmZQrhYp1GQIFGDMaOSMHNy8MUQA5AAsAEzl4jp6BiAw1FAU-gA2zaSZaWTlABZQHR1y5RwA2gCMHNUcAMwAupIA9CswsorKuIwsSAQ6QA)

**Explanation**:

`infer` - expects one argument `cb`. I have created extra `Cb` generic parameter to infer `cb` argument `as much as possible`. Once you create a generic for function argument, TS will try to infer it. If you are interested in type inference on function arguments please check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Please keep in mind that once you have provided explicit type `MagicType<number>` for function in :

```js
const f1: MagicType<number> = async (str, keys) => {
    return '42'
}
```

TypeScript don't do any inference work it just uses `MagicType<number>`.

Consider this example:

```js
const arr: ReadonlyArray<string> = ['a', 'b'] as const;
```

You may think that TS is able to figure out that apart from being `ReadonlyArray<string>` `arr` is also `['a','b']`, but it is not true. Array `arr` is just a `ReadonlyArray<string>` it is no more possible to infer literal type of array element.

**UPDATE**

You can also use :

```js
type MagicType<K> = (str: string, keys: Array<K>) => Promise<unknown>;

const infer = <Type, Cb = MagicType<Type>>(cb: Cb) => cb

const infered = infer<string>(async (str, keys) => '42')
```

**Explanation:**
**`infer`** - function expects two generic parameters:

- first one `Type`, represents type of element in the array `keys`. It refers to `K` in your example.
- second one `Cb`  has default parameter, it means that you don't need to provide second parameter to your `infer` fucntion. Second parameter `Cb` is just a `MagicType<Type>`. Hence, just like in your example, you need to provide type of `keys` element.

We still don't have any geeric for return type of `Cb`. We don't need, since TS is able to infer it for us.

You can also replace `Promise<any>` with `Promise<unknown>`

P.S. I'm not a big fan of using `explicit` generics.

---

This case is not strictly related to our problem, but it might be helpful for you:

Consider this very simple example:

```js
const returnType = <Return,>(cb: () => Return) => cb()

const result = returnType(() => 42) // number
```

TS is able to infer `Return` generic

Comment: Thank you for this great answer!
The first approach:1)"you are providing explicit return type" is out of scope, since the output type is very complicated
The second approach assumes that the infer function (which should be a utility function) will have the key type hardcoded by <number>, but it should be specified by the caller, on a case-by-case basis.
I tried to generalize it, however, it seems there is not solution (that I can think of) without downsides. Have a look here: shorturl.at/tNOS0
I think, however, I'll go with the last variant, since the tradeoffs seem to be the least painful

Comment: @paroxyzm made an update. AFAIK, there is no `elegant` solution

Comment: This is exactly what I came up with, the downside with this approach is that, once you specify ANY TYPE, the inference will no longer work... so, saying infer<string> will throw the inference out of the window... so the type of infered is now () => Promise<unknown>... :(

Comment: I don't have any other solutions :(

Comment: That's fine, would you mind sharing how did you come up with the solution? How does it work?

Comment: @paroxyzm do you mean the last one, after `UPDATE` ?

Comment: No, the original solution. The infer function is an identity function but with some TS-hacks, just to make inference happening... But I don't understand how it works

Comment: @paroxyzm this `const infer = <Cb extends MagicType<number>>(cb: Cb) => cb` ?

Comment: @paroxyzm made an update

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I learned a lot from it, but I'm hesitant to close it.
It seems that the MagicType does not exist in TS, unfortunately, which should be the accepted answer :)