# Is it possible to partially specify a function type in TypeScript while having other parts of the type inferred?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am looking for the cleanest way to specify some kinds of types when authoring JavaScript (with TypeScript annotations [via the JSDoc-compatible declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html). But I think that specific use case is irrelevant; I think anything that would work in TypeScript proper could probably be adapted to the JSDoc syntax).

There are several questions out there about "partially-specified" TypeScript types, that also involve multiple generic parameters. I am just not fluent enough in this area to be able to tell whether [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69836857/partially-specifying-the-type-of-a-function-type-in-typescript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference) or  [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) or [pull requests](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/54047) are the same as mine, or my answer can be derived from them. Most of those questions seem to have more to do with explicitly specifying generic type parameters via casting (or specifying some but not others).

Here's what I want to do:

```
type Mapping<A,B> = (a: A) => B

interface DomainObject {
  id: string
}

const property = <T,K extends keyof T>(name: K) => {
  return (object: T) => object[name];
};

const pipe = <A,B,C>(f: (a: A) => B, g: (b: B) => C) => {
  return (a: A) => g(f(a));
}

// What I would like to do, to maximize inference -- both for during development, to assist with
// type hinting, but also to keep the code compact and clear, is tell TypeScript that the first
// argument to this is a DomainObject and have it infer both that the argument to property("id")
// is DomainObject and that the return type is string.

const idTwice /*: (d: DomainObject) => (infer) */ = pipe(
  property("id"),
  (s: string) => s + s
);
```

In other words, I want to do this, but without having to specify the return type explicitly:

```
// In other words, I want to do this, without having to specify the return type of 'string',
// which is inferrable from the type of the argument DomainObject. I've seen the 'infer'
// keyword used to perform similar operations but do not know whether it is applicable here
// or how it might be used, or whether this is possible at all with how TypeScript works.
// (Sometimes it has limitations that surprise me.)

const idTwiceWorks: Mapping<DomainObject,string> = pipe(
  property("id"),
  (s: string) => s + s
);
```

Here's an attempt to specify a partially-inferred function type, which does not work but illustrates what I'm going for:

```
// Here's another attempt to specify a function type where the argument type is specified and the
// return type is inferred. Not allowed this way, either.

type Map1<A> = <B>(a: A) => B

const idTwice1: Map1<DomainObject> = pipe(
  property("id"),
  (s: string) => s + s
);
```

Here's a workaround that *does* work by using a function to essentially "cast" the input parameter:

```
// I can do it with no type hinting at all if I synthesize a function for that purpose ...

const asDomainObject: (d: DomainObject) => DomainObject = (d) => d

const pipe3 = <A,B,C,D>(f: (a: A) => B, g: (b: B) => C, h: (c: C) => D) => {
  return (a: A) => h(g(f(a)));
}

const idTwice2 = pipe3(
  asDomainObject,
  property("id"),
  (s: string) => s + s
);
```

So hopefully that clarifies what I'd like to do. Is it possible? What would be syntax that would do it?

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=48&pc=1#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-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-WNirRZsPxXD8KzCEA4d+XJisbXNuBy3n2ThL4DQFxwniy4IxWUNGQuUEIQred4lVJ0kAsDRB-h8znBVRCsSWWkQHYCuE0HuZQZGgTXCLmP3kJyFD0Zwwq2SQL3IwlFjAoJf2HbcS1rSM5Q4ZCXRBL5MgLXEHJYQgANcdZP5YW5M2h0VB1dAKwxiqhCBe3LDplPjG71IgW4SWLrSEGQdAMHe0ocG7IwDK3F6zJ+qzjxsgGHOvaY7wfcHWCAA) with all the code above, hopefully faithfully transcribed.

Comment: There is no way for the compiler to find a relation between what you are trying to do and `DomainObject` without an explicit mentioning the `DomainObject`

Comment: (continued) You will have to specify `DomainObject` somewhere, otherwise, the closest that we can possibly get is just `{id: string}`

Comment: Would something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKvM8m) work?